# Mathematical analysis - problem with calculating limit

Tags: analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I need to calculate one limit and I have big problems. I would be very thankful if someone could help me...

This is the limit I need to find: 
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2^n + n\sin{n}}{\log_2{n} + e^n}
$$

Any hint/explanation would be very helpful!

Comment: Are $n$ the variable of your functions? If the variable is $n$, then the limit is the same expression, because $n$ is a constant recpect to $x$.

Answer (score 1):

$$0\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^n +n\sin n}{\log_2n+e^n} \le \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^n +n}{e^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{2}{e}\right)^n+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{e^n}=0+0=0.$$

Comment: Thank you very much! That was really helpful!

Comment: I forgot, I'm sorry... Thank you very much again!

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: $0 < f(n) < 2\cdot \dfrac{2^n}{e^n}= 2\cdot \left(\dfrac{2}{e}\right)^n, n \ge N_0$